# facebook like button won't show comment box

Tags: facebook-like

I have created a site that includes facebook 'like' buttons (see http://www.rupertheath.com) and they work except, when you click them, no comment box appears. When I first installed the buttons, the comment box did appear but I've spent some time styling the buttons (for positioning) and seem to have stopped that functionality working.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, you set `overflow: hidden` on a parent container:

```
<div class="socialmediabuttons">
    ....
</div>
```

Remove that style and the comment box should reappear. Note that you need to change other styles as well as it will break the hairlines around the social media buttons (but it is doable).

**EDIT**

Try something along the lines of:

```
.socialmediabuttons {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
+   height: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 25px !important;
    margin-left: 20px;
-   overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: You got it! I was trying to clear floats but that doesn't appear to be needed. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome and please consider accepting the answer (this indicates to others that your problem is solved).